# Django import order causing error with default user model on class imports from another app

Tags: python, django, django-models

When referencing models from my core app 'core_hr' in my custom user model app where I overrode AbstractBaseUser to define a new user model I received an error

Until I tried to import models from another django app into my overridden custom user model app I had never seen this error. All my apps are in installed apps.

```
"AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.Employee' that has not been installed

## models.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone

# ---->from core_hr.models import Passport, RegistryOfStay <-----
from .managers import CustomUserManager
from ####.storage_backends import PublicMediaStorage, PrivateMediaStorage
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

name_validator = RegexValidator(r'^[a-z A-Z]*$', 'Only Alphabetic characters allowed')


class Employee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    employment_statuses = (
        ('ap','Applicant'),
        ('trial', 'Initial Training'),
        ('em', 'Employed'),
        ('ps','Pause')
    )
    genders = (('M', 'male'),('F', 'female'))
    # core information
    full_name = models.CharField(_('Surname, Given Names as on passport'), validators=[name_validator], max_length=25, blank=False, null=True)

    #employment data
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=genders)
    employee_id_number = models.CharField(_('employee id number'), max_length=20, null=True)

    # activity Status
    employment_status = models.CharField(choices=employment_statuses, max_length=30)
    employment_status_note = models.TextField(max_length=500)


    # contact information
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_(' email address'), unique=True)
    personal_email = models.EmailField(_('Personal Email Address'), unique=True)


    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()


    def get_contact_info(self):
        try:
            return f"{self.phone_number}, {self.email}, {self.personal_email}"
        except:
            return "Error during retrieval of contact info, perhaps it isn't complete"

    def passport_complete(self):
        from core_hr.models import Passport
        try:
            passport = Passport.objects.get(owner=self)
            return passport.data_complete
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return ["Couldn't query passport, perhaps it was not created?", False]

    def ros_form_complete(self):
        from core_hr.models import RegistryOfStay
        try:
            ros_form = RegistryOfStay.objects.get(owner=self)
            return ros_form.data_complete
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return ["Couldn't query Registry of stay, perhaps it was not created", False]
        pass



    @property
    def core_documents_complete(self):
        completion_statuses = [self.passport_complete(), self.ros_form_complete()]
        return  False if False in completion_statuses else True


    def first_name(self):
        try:
            return str(self.full_name.split()[1])
        except:
            pass
    def middle_name(self):
        try:
            return str(self.full_name.split()[2])
        except:
            pass
    def last_name(self):
        try:
            return str(self.full_name.split()[0])
        except:
            pass

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.full_name} {self.email}"
```

After reading:
[AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model .. that has not been installed and created AbstractUser models not able to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699598/auth-user-model-refers-to-model-that-has-not-been-installed-and-created-abstr)

I decided to comment out:

`---->from core_hr.models import Passport, RegistryOfStay <-----`

and add model class function scope imports in my models utility functions (not sure if this is a great idea?)
 PEP8 suggests not ->> [import at module level or at function level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614051/import-at-module-level-or-at-function-level) (but answer implies it is somewhat situational)

```
        from core_hr.models import Passport
        try:
            passport = Passport.objects.get(owner=self)
            return passport.data_complete
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return ["Couldn't query passport, perhaps it was not created?", False]
```

And it fixed the problem.
I wish to understand why the function level imports fixed the issue.

I am really just concerned with unintended side effects later on in the project, as well as if this is a best practice or a no-no.

Edit :

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for docker_files.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

# Build paths inside the docker_files like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates')
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/


#
# STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

#

# static files settings

STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

USE_S3 = os.getenv('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    # STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    # STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
    # s3 media settings
    PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = '#####.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'

    PRIVATE_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'private'
    PRIVATE_FILE_STORAGE = '#####.storage_backends.PrivateMediaStorage'

else:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')



# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY','change me to a real key')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG=True
if os.environ.get('DEV'):
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']






INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    #'livereload',
    'users',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Local
    # 'debug_toolbar'
    '######',
    'core_hr',
    'schedules',
    'org',
    # extensions
    'django_countries',
    'django_nose',
    'storages',
    'django_extensions'

]




TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-cover',
    '--cover-package=core_hr',
    '--cover-package=####',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    #'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript',
    #'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = '####.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = '####.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases
if os.environ.get('PROD'):
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE"),
            "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE"),
            "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER", "user"),
            "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD", "password"),
            "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST", "localhost"),
            "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT", "5432"),
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'devdb.sqlite3'),
        }
    }

# CUSTOM USER MODEL
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Employee'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
```

Comment: can you show your settings.py?

Comment: settings is up now.

Comment: i am not sure because i didnt see other models. But may be you need to use get_user_model. Django docs says: `If you reference User directly (for example, by referring to it in a foreign key), your code will not work in projects where the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting has been changed to a different user model.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: I think this is a deeper bug that has to do with import ordering and circular references. I don't know enough to say but I did a little more research and it looks like django module importing has some unknown behavior with regards to initialization of the user model. I will switch to get user model if it causes problems, thanks !