# What is best-practice for importing classes or functions to into a `unittest` test module

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

What is best-practice for importing classes or functions to into a `unittest` test module?

Suppose, I've the following `common` package in my project root, and I'd like to test `common/utils.py` in `common/tests/test_utils.py`:

```
common
├── __init__.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_utils.py
└── utils.py
```

Should I import classes or functions at the top-level of the test module, or inside the the individual test cases (see below)?

```
import unittest


class TestUtils(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_object_factory(self):
        from ..utils import object_factory
        object_factory = _(foo=1, bar='bar', baz={'a': 1, 'b': (2, 3)})
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(o, 'foo'))
        self.assertEqual(o.foo, 1)
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(o, 'bar'))
        self.assertEqual(o.bar, 'bar')
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(o, 'baz'))
        self.assertEqual(o.baz, {'a': 1, 'b': (2, 3)})
```

Comment: I would say absolute imports are usually the better way, and this case is no different - see the more general [question about absolute vs relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module).

Comment: What do you mens by absolute import? I have to import relative to the `tests` package using `..`?

Comment: Absolute import would be `from common.utils import ...`, or `from project.common.utils import ...`, depending on your project root, relative is what you do (`from ..utils import ...`). I thought your question was related to this, maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - I wanted to know whether it’s good practice to place the import inside the test case `test_object_factory` or outside at the top-level.

Comment: Ah, you mean local vs global import - sorry, I got this wrong. Generally, I would always [prefer global imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614051/import-at-module-level-or-at-function-level), the same goes for test code. Local imports are sometimes needed to avoid cyclic references or side effects, but apart from that I would not use them.